# How to tune Notes on OS X to use plain text or not to reformat quotes?

Tags: copy-paste, notes.app, accessibility

As technical guy, I do hate the markup support in [Notes.app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notes_(application)) and I would prefer to be just a smart text one.

Here is my wishlist:

- Use a different font, like a fixed width one
- Drop any font/color/size on text paste
- Prevent replacing quotes with [smart-quotes/curly-quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_marks_in_English#Smart_quotes) (I like this while typing an email but not here where I copy/paste even code!)

I suspect that some of these could be obtained using some hidden preferences options. Anyway, if you know other 3rd party applications that could replace Notes, let me know. Still I do not want to lose the ability to access notes from iOS!

Comment: what OS? Yosemite does all that.

Answer (score 52):

## Notes

**Notes.app** in OS X 10.10 can do all you request:

- Font colour, size, and family can be set through the **Format** menu.
- Substitutions and smart quote behaviour are managed through the **Edit > Substitutions** sub-menu.

[image: Screen shot of Notes.app in OS X 10.10]

### Beyond Notes: Text Wrangler

If you need more than Notes.app offers, try [Text Wrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) or the capable free version of [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html) from Bare Bones.

Comment: I finally find the way to stop Notes in macOS from having weird quote and double quotes by disabling the Smart Quotes in Edit -> Substitutions, thanks

Comment: The only problem is when you copy and paste in text (and invariably don't remember to use "match style" or it's keyboard equivalent). I still sometimes find myself resorting to TextEdit for that reason...

Comment: Is it possible to convert existing text in notes with substitutions back to not use any substitutions anymore?

Comment: @asmaier please can you [ask a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). A new question will attract more attention – and hopefully answers – than a comment.

Comment: Oh thank god I found this!

Comment: Ohhh man, thanks so much!! I have been facing the issue with quotes for years!

Answer (score 0):

BigSur Notes Application still offers this. However a more permanent solution is to go into preferences -> keyboard -> text

On the right side you can uncheck "use smart quotes and dashes"

Now the notes application will use plain text "straight" quotes

[image: uncheck it]

Comment: Won't this affect other apps for which the OP may want to have the use of smart quotes and dashes? If so, this is a rather heavy-handed remedy not germane specifically to the Notes app.

Comment: If concerned about this you can also leave smart quotes on, but instead select straight quotes as the last option.