# How do I hyperlink 'text' within a note in the macOS Notes app?

Tags: macos, notes.app, url

If you copy and paste a link from Safari into the Notes app, it is pasted as text that is also hyperlinked. However, I haven't been able to find a way to do this in the Notes app directly.

I've tried using markdown, for example:

```
[Google](www.google.com)
```

However, it only made the part in the parentheses `www.google.com` a hyperlink instead of just displaying `Google` and making this the active hyperlink.

How can I hyperlink 'text' within a  note in the macOS Notes app?

Comment: I'm confused. isn't www.google.com the hyperlink? Isn't all of it visible?

Comment: I wanted a link like [this](www.google.com), so basically one which shows text different to the link itself. Didn't realize it was so simple.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's quite simple – just highlight the text you want to make a hyperlink of, press **⌘K**, and then paste the link in.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this in the iOS app?

Comment: This isn't always allowed, not quite sure why but I think it might have to do with how I have a corporate laptop and don't sync my Notes to iCloud. Tsk.

Comment: That's quite strange, you could also try going to the menu bar and selecting **Edit > Add Link...**, and that should work as well. Unless it's grayed out

Answer (score 3):

Use full path: Select text, choose Edit > Add Link... (or Command-K), finally paste the link

Answer (score 0):

As per [this Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/notes/apde615d29c2/mac), Enable Smart Links and then if you type a URL or paste any link & press Return key, it should be clickable.

How to enable Smart Links :

In the Notes app  on your Mac, click a note in the notes list or double-click a note in gallery view, then choose Edit > Substitutions > Smart Links (a tick shows it’s on).

Before :

[image]

(image taken from : [How to tune Notes on OS X to use plain text or not to reformat quotes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168494/how-to-tune-notes-on-os-x-to-use-plain-text-or-not-to-reformat-quotes))

After :

[image]

(image taken from : https://www.reddit.com/r/bearapp/comments/8gqcux/what_are_smart_links/)